# Couldn't find package KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net 5 application published on Azure, that is returning a **500 Internal Error**.

After disabling custom errors on `web.config` file, this is the error being displayed:

[image: KRE not]

It's an odd behaviour, since everything on `web.config` seems fine. Directories are correct and I've checked them:

[image: Filezilla screenshot]

And then, there's the `web.config` file, which seems also correct:

[image: web.config]

Packages on `project.json` are in `beta2`.
Runtime on project is set to **KRE x86 beta2**

What might be happening? Looks like a problem on Azure, the website runs fine on the development machine.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but is there anything in the `KRE-CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta2` folder?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Yes, there's the whole thing.

Comment: @epiplon: your site root should point to wwwroot right which has the web.config ? The error message is trying to find the package inside site/packages when ideally it should be '..\approot\packages'

Comment: @SuhasJoshi Then it's ignoring the `web.config`, since **kre-package-path** is pointing to the right folder.

Comment: Any update on this by any chance? Experiencing the same issue and pretty confused about it.